# Why Outer join binds values from outered table

Tags: sql, oracle

Is this oracle error or am I not understanding something?

```
select let1, let2, nvl(let2, 'z') fn_let2
from
  (select 1 num, 'a' let1 from dual) t1
  left outer join (select 2 num, 'E' let2 from dual where 0=1) t2
    on (t1.num = t2.num);
```

> t1 - return 1, 'a'
>
> t2 - no rows due to 0=1

Now we left outer join both, so we should get all from t1 padded with nulls, but no...

Binded 'E' is taken to results.

> 'a', 'E', 'z'

Even funnier, that function on let2 works correctly, so nvl(let2, 'z') - return 'z'.

I am using Oracle 10.2

Comment: Could not reproduce on Oracle 11gR2 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/503b4d/1) and 12c

Comment: what do you mean  "now we left outer join both,"  ? ..show the code

Comment: @scaisEdge as far as I understand that's the whole code. OP actually created an MCVE, we don't get to see that very often :)

Comment: `select  let2, nvl(let2, 'z')` returns   `'E', 'z'`, really ?

Comment: i have tried  and work correctly

Comment: Can you please show the query and the output exactly?

Comment: Since we have trouble reproducing your issue, can you provide us more information about your setup? Are you execuing this query directly (through SQLPlus) or through some kind of an application? Have you tried to run this query on a clean database, i.e. to install your version of Oracle from scratch? Can you include the full output of `select * from v$version;` in your question?

Comment: And, by the way, what is the result of this query: `select c, nvl(c, 'a') from (select 1 from dual) left outer join (select 'E' c from dual) on 1 = 0` ?

Comment: Oracle 10g Enterprise edition
Oracle 10.2.0.4.0
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: V the same
NLSRTL V the same.

Sorry env is thru virtual desktop without copy/pasts possibilty.

Comment: select c, nvl(c, 'a') from (select 1 from dual) left outer join (select 'E' c from dual) on 1 = 0 
returns
E, a

Comment: @MaKaM It's getting weirder. Please, add this information into the question itself. You can edit your posts: press the "edit" button right under the question.

Comment: Can you just try to execute the following query? This is just a try in a black hole: `select let1, let2, nvl(let2, 'z') fn_let2
from
  (select 1 num, 'a' let1 from dual) t1
  left outer join (select /*+ materialize */ 2 num, 'E' let2 from dual where 0=1) t2
    on (t1.num = t2.num);`